# Php save file to specific location?

Tags: php

i have this

```
<?php
$canvasImg = $_POST['img'];    
$data = base64_decode($canvasImg);
$File = $_POST['imgname'].jpg; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $data);  
fclose($Handle);
?>
```

this saves image.jpg to my theme root folder. how to save it to server root folder ... /Public_html/wp-content/uploads ?

thanks

Comment: After checking other's people answers, also take look at http://pl1.php.net/constants.predefined

Answer (score 5):

Use file_put_contents();

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.blahblahblah.com/logo.gif');
file_put_contents('./myDir/myFile.gif', $image);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $link= $_POST['img'];
  $destdir = '/public_html/wp-content/uploads';
  $img=file_get_contents($link);
  file_put_contents($destdir.substr($link,strrpos($link,'/')),$img);
?>
```

Let me know if it worked out for you =).

Comment: gave me error Warning: file_get_contents(,iVBORw0K ... so on

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB28AAAS7CAYAAAC2HvHJAAit............... gave me long file name which doesn't  fit in this comment box

Answer (score 0):

`$File` is your path and filename, you can change folder from it (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).