# I can't echo an image from my SQL database, it just shows the alt image

Tags: php, mysql

I stored an image in and SQL database as a BLOB file but when I try to echo it using

```
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM imgtest";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['img'] ).'"/>';
              }
            }
```

It shows only the alt image icon, I also tried `echo $row['img'];` but that only showed me the code of the image.

Comment: it's a very bad practice saving images inside SQL databases. consider saving only the path and saving the images on your filesystem

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make a system where people upload images to the database and can see them again on the site, is that also possible if I make them upload the image to the filesystem?

Comment: sure, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168681/php-save-file-to-specific-location/22168906 , it's cleaner, more maintainable, easier but more importantly, faster

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your img name in a row of your table named for example "img_name" and call it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imgtest";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $my_img '<img src="'. $row['img_name'] .'"/>';
    }
}
```

And put this in your HTML to render your image:

```
<?= $my_img ?>
```